# How can I store a query string in a session variable on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm using a query string attached to external links to identify vendors visiting my Wordpress site. I need to save the query (currently using $_GET[]) to a session or cookie but am having no luck with either. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? (WP 3.8.2)

FYI I've been through and through other posts but turned up nothing useful...

Comment: `$_SESSION['id']=$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url example: `example.com?vendor=something`

You can save to session or cookie like that:

```
$_SESSION['vendor'] = $_GET['vendor'];
setcookie('vendor', $_GET['vendor'], time()+86400); //For 1 day
```

Comment: Wordpress still won't allow me to set a session variable... any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that, I needed to wrap it in isset, doh! Thanks for your help!